# Handlebars.js - keeping values column aligned

Tags: json, node.js, handlebars.js

I'm currently working with Handlebars.js (v 4.0.10) within a Node.js environment.

I'm trying to produce a JSON string with the following format, but have been unsuccessful in finding a solution.

Given the following JSON object:

```
{
  foo: [
    {bar: 1, baz: "test"},
    {bar: 2, baz: "test", qux: "somethingElse"},
    {bar: 234, baz: "testtest"},
    {bar: 34674, baz: "a", qux: "moreText"},
  ]
}
```

How can I use handlebars to produce the following:

```
"{
  foo: [
    {bar: 1,         baz: "test"},
    {bar: 2,         baz: "test",      qux: "somethingElse"},
    {bar: 234,       baz: "testtest"},
    {bar: 34674,     baz: "a",         qux: "moreText"},
  ]
}"
```

Notice how the properties are aligned vertically with eachother.  I have a crude implementation working, however I'm not sure how to properly preserve white space in a way that will correctly align the text.

This is my template file:

```
{
  "foo": [
    {{#each foo}}
      { "bar": {{bar}},     "baz": "{{{baz}}}"{{#if qux}},      "qux": "{{{qux}}}"{{/if}} }{{#unless @last}},{{/unless}}
    {{/each}}
  ]
}
```

The issue is that if a property has a value that is of a different length (ie, 234 (character count of 3) vs 34674 (character count of 5)), it produces that "stairstepping" effect, and properties aren't vertically aligned with each other.  Thus, it would render like this:

```
"{
  foo: [
    {bar: 1,     baz: "test"},
    {bar: 2,     baz: "test",      qux: "somethingElse"},
    {bar: 234,     baz: "testtest"},
    {bar: 34674,     baz: "a",      qux: "moreText"},
  ]
}"
```

Anyone have a magic trick up their sleeve which might be able to help out?

Comment: Couldn’t you just insert a tab character?

Comment: Could you elaborate more?  Insert it where and how?  I can use tabs other than spaces, but it's still a matter of figuring out "how many" tabs/spaces to use to cause a nice vertical alignment of properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can add tabs to your variables:

```
res.render('test', {
  test1: "12345\t",
  test2: "12345678\t",
});
```

Then in your template:

```
<pre>
    {{test1}}block
    {{test2}}block
</pre>
```

This should produce something like this depending on what tag you put it in:
[image: example output]